# R: get the mean of responses only if previous response is of a a specific type

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I have been puzzling over getting the mean of a response under conditions quite some time now and I would appreciate any help of a clear mind at the moment.

```
    Trial <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4","5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9", "10", "10") 
    Session <- c("2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6", "2", "6") 
    Type <- c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x") 
    Response <- c("3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "4", "6", "1", "3", "4", "2", "5", "1", "6", "5", "4", "6", "1", "3", "4") 
    df <- data.frame(Trial, Session, Type, Response)
```

I have a bunch of responses for several sessions. How can I get the mean of the "Response" for **Session 2 of Type x** but *only if the previous "Response"* is of **Session 6 AND Type y**?

Expected output is just the mean response (numeric).

Thank you for your time. If additional information is needed let me know.

[image: Here is an example of the dataframe imported in R]

Comment: Please, add your data as produced by `dput` and also the expect output.

Comment: Agreed with PaulS - we can't copy a screenshot into R.

Comment: You are totally right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::lag` to get the lagged vectors for your conditional statements:

```r
 mean(df$Response[which(df$Session == 2 & 
                        df$Type == "x" & 
                        dplyr::lag(df$Session) == 6 &
                        dplyr::lag(df$Type) == "y")])
#> [1] 3.333333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- data.frame(Trial = rep(1:10, each = 2),
                 Session = rep(c(2, 6), 10),
                 Type = rep(rep(c("x", "y"), len = 7), 
                            times = c(4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2)),
                 Response = c(2, 4:6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3,
                              4, 2, 3))

df
#>    Trial Session Type Response
#> 1      1       2    x        2
#> 2      1       6    x        4
#> 3      2       2    x        5
#> 4      2       6    x        6
#> 5      3       2    y        3
#> 6      3       6    y        2
#> 7      4       2    x        3
#> 8      4       6    x        3
#> 9      5       2    y        4
#> 10     5       6    y        2
#> 11     6       2    y        3
#> 12     6       6    y        4
#> 13     7       2    x        5
#> 14     7       6    x        2
#> 15     8       2    y        2
#> 16     8       6    y        3
#> 17     9       2    y        3
#> 18     9       6    y        4
#> 19    10       2    x        2
#> 20    10       6    x        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here is an other approach: The conditions are the same:

Interstingly if we replace

`mutate(mean = ifelse(x == TRUE, sum(Response[x==TRUE])/ nrow(df[x==TRUE, ]), NA))`

by

`mutate(mean = ifelse(x == TRUE, mean(Response), NA))` we will get `mean = 3.25`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(
    Session == 2 & 
      Type == "x" & 
      lag(Session) == 6 &
      lag(Type) == "y" ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE
  )) %>% 
  mutate(mean = ifelse(x == TRUE, sum(Response[x==TRUE])/
                                        nrow(df[x==TRUE, ]), NA)) %>% 
  filter (., is.na(mean)==FALSE) %>% 
  distinct(mean)
```

```
      mean
1 3.333333
```